# Timestamp Mysql Date_From as default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Hi I need to resolve next problem.

I have a row in mysql:

'start_at'  and 'ends_at'

They are Timestamps type.
 I need to set default value of `ends_at`  plus 7 days from `starts_at`

something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `a_to_b`
MODIFY COLUMN `ends_at`  timestamp NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 604800' AFTER `starts_at`;
```

If i am right in MSSQL i can do DATE_FROM();
 How can I do this in MySql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql does not allow computation in table structure. You need to do the insert afterwards:

```
insert into myDate (endTime) values ((interval 7 day + current_timestamp))
```